# Comparing data to model and returning a chi squared value

Tags: python, graph, statistics, physics

This is quite basic but useful to test various (9) different models using one set of data.  I have tried to make it clear and use the PEP8 formatting.

I am currently creating a version that can read CSV files to make it even faster.  I'd like any suggestions on how I could improve my code or any hints as to what I could add next.

```
import numpy
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot
import scipy.optimize
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


''' A Program That Determines The Reduced Chi Squared Value For Various Theoretical Models.'''
'''The Best Fit Parameters Are Derived Using Levenberg-Marquardt Algorithm Which Solves The Non-Linear Least Squares Problem.'''
''' Test = 1 Assumes A Linear Model '''
''' Test = 2 Assumes A Quadratic Model '''
''' Test = 3 Assumes A Cubic Model '''
''' Test = 4 Assumes A Quartic Model '''
''' Test = 5 Assumes A Quintic Model '''
''' Test = 6 Assumes A Logarithmic Model '''
''' Test = 7 Assumes A Power Law Model '''
''' Test = 8 Assumes A Exponential Model '''
''' Test = 9 Assumes A Exponential Offset Model '''


#Recorded Observed Data
xdata = numpy.array([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
ydata = numpy.array([-10, -7, 1, 5, 7, 7, 6, 7, 10, 15])
xerror = numpy.array([0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3])
yerror = numpy.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1])


#User Prompted Input Values
test=int(raw_input("Enter A Number Assigned Theoretical Model To Test: "))


#Theoretical Models To Be Tested
if test == 1:
    print 'Testing linear model', '\n'

    #Scipy Optimise cuve_fit Model Produces Expected Values Using A Linear Model
    def func(x, a, b):
        return a*x + b

    #Constants Of Theoretical Model
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
    print 'Constant Ax is',("%.2f" %popt[0])
    print 'Constant B is',("%.2f" %popt[1]), '\n'

if test == 2:
    print 'Testing quadratic model', '\n'

    #Scipy Optimise cuve_fit Model Produces Expected Values Using A Quadratic Model Polynomial Model
    def func(x, a, b, c):
        return a*x**2 + b*x + c

    #Constants Of Theoretical Model
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
    print 'Constant Ax^2 is',("%.2f" %popt[0])
    print 'Constant Bx is',("%.2f" %popt[1])
    print 'Constant C is',("%.2f" %popt[2]), '\n'   

if test == 3:
    print 'Testing cubic model', '\n'

    #Scipy Optimise cuve_fit Model Produces Expected Values Using A Cubic Model Polynomial Model
    def func(x, a, b, c, d):
        return a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d

    #Constants Of Theoretical Model
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
    print 'Constant Ax^3 is',("%.2f" %popt[0])
    print 'Constant Bx^2 is',("%.2f" %popt[1])
    print 'Constant Cx is',("%.2f" %popt[2])
    print 'Constant D is',("%.2f" %popt[3]), '\n'

if test == 4:
    print 'Testing quartic model', '\n'

    #Scipy Optimise cuve_fit Model Produces Expected Values Using A Quartic Polynomial Model
    def func(x, a, b, c, d, e):
        return a*x**4 + b*x**3 + c*x**2 + d*x + e

    #Constants Of Theoretical Model
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
    print 'Constant Ax^4 is',("%.2f" %popt[0])
    print 'Constant Bx^3 is',("%.2f" %popt[1])
    print 'Constant Cx^2 is',("%.2f" %popt[2])
    print 'Constant Dx is',("%.2f" %popt[3])
    print 'Constant E is',("%.2f" %popt[4]), '\n'

if test == 5:
    print 'Testing quintic model', '\n'

    #Scipy Optimise cuve_fit Model Produces Expected Values Using A Quintic Polynomial Model
    def func(x, a, b, c, d, e, f):
        return a*x**5 + b*x**4 + c*x**3 + d*x**2 + e*x + f

    #Constants Of Theoretical Model
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
    print 'Constant Ax^5 is',("%.2f" %popt[0])
    print 'Constant Bx^4 is',("%.2f" %popt[1])
    print 'Constant Cx^3 is',("%.2f" %popt[2])
    print 'Constant Dx^2 is',("%.2f" %popt[3])
    print 'Constant Ex is',("%.2f" %popt[4])
    print 'Constant F is',("%.2f" %popt[5]), '\n'

if test == 6:
    print 'Testing logarithmic model', '\n'

    #Scipy Optimise cuve_fit Model Produces Expected Values Using A Logarithmic Model
    def func(x, a, b):
        return a*numpy.log(x)+ b 

    #Constants Of Least Squared Theoretical Model
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
    print 'Constant A is',("%.2f" %popt[0])
    print 'Constant Bx is',("%.2f" %popt[1]), '\n'

if test == 7:
    print 'Testing power law model', '\n'

    #Scipy Optimise cuve_fit Model Produces Expected Values Using A Power Law Model
    def func(x, a, b):
        return a*(x**b) 

    #Constants Of Least Squared Theoretical Model
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
    print 'Constant A is',("%.2f" %popt[0])
    print 'Constant B is',("%.2f" %popt[1]), '\n'

if test == 8:
    print 'Testing exponential model', '\n'

    #Scipy Optimise cuve_fit Model Produces Expected Values Using A Exponential Model
    def func(x, a, b, c):
        return a*numpy.exp(b*x + c)

    #Constants Of Least Squared Theoretical Model
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
    print 'Constant A is',("%.2f" %popt[0])
    print 'Constant Bx is',("%.2f" %popt[1])
    print 'Constant C is',("%.2f" %popt[2]), '\n'

if test == 9:
    print 'Testing exponetial offset model', '\n'

    #Scipy Optimise cuve_fit Model Produces Expected Values Using A Exponential Offset Model
    def func(x, a, b, c, d):
        return a*numpy.exp(b*x + c) + d 

    #Constants Of Least Squared Theoretical Model
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
    print 'Constant A is',("%.2f" %popt[0])
    print 'Constant Bx is',("%.2f" %popt[1])
    print 'Constant C is',("%.2f" %popt[2])
    print 'Constant D is',("%.2f" %popt[3]), '\n'


#Derived Chi Squared Value For This Model
chi_squared = numpy.sum(((func(xdata, *popt)-ydata)/xerror)**2)
reduced_chi_squared = (chi_squared)/(len(xdata)-len(popt))
print 'The degrees of freedom for this test is', len(xdata)-len(popt)
print 'The chi squared value is: ',("%.2f" %chi_squared)
print 'The reduced chi squared value is: ',("%.2f" %reduced_chi_squared)


#Observed Values Are Plotted With Expected Values
matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(xdata, ydata, s=0)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(xdata,func(xdata, *popt), label='Theoretical Model')
matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar(xdata, ydata, xerr=xerror, yerr=yerror, linestyle="", color='red')
matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel(' Observed Values For x ')
matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel(' f(x)')
matplotlib.pyplot.legend(loc='lower right')
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### PEP8

You say you want to follow PEP8, but you're pretty far from it. A couple of examples:

> ```
> #Recorded Observed Data
> xdata = numpy.array([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
> test=int(raw_input("Enter A Number Assigned Theoretical Model To Test: "))
> print 'Constant Ax is',("%.2f" %popt[0])
> reduced_chi_squared = (chi_squared)/(len(xdata)-len(popt))
> ```

This is how it should be, look carefully to find the differences on each line:

```
# Recorded Observed Data
xdata = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
test = int(raw_input("Enter A Number Assigned Theoretical Model To Test: "))
print 'Constant Ax is', ("%.2f" % popt[0])
reduced_chi_squared = chi_squared / (len(xdata) - len(popt))
```

You have any of these kind of issues. You can use the `pep8` command line tool to point out all the violations. Install with `pip install pep8`.

#### Logical flow

Your many `if test == 1`, `if test == 2` statements are mutually exclusive, so you really should use `elif`:

```
if test == 1:
    # ...
elif test == 2:
    # ...
# ...
```

Even better, put the content of each of those `if` blocks into functions, and then make a dictionary of those functions, for example:

```
def test_linear_model():
    # ...


def test_quadratic_model():
    # ...

commands = {
    1: test_linear_model,
    2: test_quadratic_model,
    # ...
}
```

So that you can run the right commands with:

```
commands[test]()
```

To use the `func` and `popt` defined in each function, return them! For example:

```
def test_linear_model():
    print 'Testing linear model', '\n'

    #Scipy Optimise cuve_fit Model Produces Expected Values Using A Linear Model
    def func(x, a, b):
        return a*x + b

    #Constants Of Theoretical Model
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
    print 'Constant Ax is',("%.2f" %popt[0])
    print 'Constant B is',("%.2f" %popt[1]), '\n'
    return func, popt
```

And then you can call the selected command like this:

```
func, popt = commands[test]()
```

So that the `chi_squared =` line will work.

#### Code organization

You should not just dump your code in the global namespace. You should have all functionality inside functions. The main method that triggers everything can be in a `main` function, which you can start like this:

```
def main():
    commands = {
        1: test_linear_model,
        2: test_quadratic_model,
        # ...
    }

    # User Prompted Input Values
    test = int(raw_input("Enter A Number Assigned Theoretical Model To Test: "))
    func, popt = commands[test]()

    #Derived Chi Squared Value For This Model
    chi_squared = numpy.sum(((func(xdata, *popt) - ydata) / xerror) ** 2)
    reduced_chi_squared = chi_squared / (len(xdata) - len(popt))
    print 'The degrees of freedom for this test is', len(xdata) - len(popt)
    print 'The chi squared value is: ', ("%.2f" % chi_squared)
    print 'The reduced chi squared value is: ', ("%.2f" % reduced_chi_squared)

    # ...        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I was looking at using the functions but I cannot see how I could incorporate a general version of the graph/chi squared calculations as I'm calling different functions.

Comment: Note sure if I understand correctly. I added to the *Logical flow* section, I hope it helps, let me know if you need something more!

Comment: Sorry it was poorly worded. Right now chi/graph is defined outside of the functions. To calculate those for the functions they'd need to be defined after the function and repeated for each function.

so

def f():
      Stuff
      chi =
      graph..

for each test

Comment: I noticed you need both `func` and `popt`. I revised again the middle part, and added one more example at the end. See what I mean?

Comment: Hey, I tried to follow the organization you have but it would keep giving me indentation errors. I followed the codes logical flow but dont see why it doesnt like the indentation of main > test > function. I pasted my progress below, sorry if this sounds stupid.

http://pastebin.com/02qHC4ra

Comment: Ignore the above, got it working http://pastebin.com/1ruL3DdK